# Automatic (unwanted) JavaFX window resize on Debian?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, debian, autoresize

I have noticed the following JavaFX behavior when implementing a JavaFX Application as follows:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    private static Stage innerStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        printSize(innerStage, "after closing the window");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        innerStage = primaryStage;
        printSize(primaryStage, "at start-up");
    }

    private static void printSize(Stage stage, String phase) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Width %s: %.1f", phase, stage.getWidth()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Height %s: %.1f", phase, stage.getHeight()));
    }
}
```

First print of the stage size gives:

```
Width at start-up: 300.0
Height at start-up: 250.0
```

while the second one gives:

```
Width after closing the window: 312.0
Height after closing the window: 284.0
```

This happens on `Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch)` but not on `Windows 10`.

Could someone explain what is causing it and let me know if there's a workaround for this such that the stage (window) does not change size by itself?

Thank you

later edit: from what I've seen, the re-size happens right after the `start` method of the JavaFX Application is done.

Comment: I get 300×250 in both print statements, using Debian 10 and JavaFX 14.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Then it might be due to the Bellsoft/Liberica JDK I'm using..
I assume you did run thihs with Oracle JDK.

Comment: OpenJDK, actually.  Build 14+36.